# Understand Reference and Dereferencing Operators?

Tags: c++

Can someone please help me understand Reference and Dereference Operators?

Here is what I read/understand so far:

```
    int myNum = 30;
    int a = &myNum;   // a equals the address where myNum is storing 30,
    int *a = &myNum;  // *a equals the value of myNum.
```

When I saw the code below I was confused:

```
    void myFunc(int &c)   // Don't understand this. shouldn't this be int *c?
    {
      c += 10;
      cout<< c;
    }

    int main()
    {
      int myNum = 30;
      myFunc(myNum);  
      cout<< myNum ;        
    }
```

`int &c` has the address to what's being passed in right? It's not the value of what's being passed in.

So when I do `c+=10` it's going to add 10 to the memory address and not the value 30. Is that correct?

BUT... when I run this...of course with all the correct includes and stuff...it works. it prints 40.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(...)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1572016/90527)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ampersand in the function parameter list for `myFunc` is not an address operator, nor a bitwise and operator.  It is a reference indicator.  It means that within `myFunc`, the parameter `c` will be an alias of whatever argument is passed to it.

Comment: So c is an alias for a. So c=a. But why put a & in there at all? If I leave out the & I get the same c=a. Is this correct? I am missing what the & is for in this case.     Thanks for you help. :)

Comment: By alias it is meant that more than one name refers to _exactly_ the same thing in memory.  So when you call `myFunc(myNum)` and `myFunc` is declared as `myFunc(int& c)` then within the body of `myFunc` whatever you do to `c` is done to `myNum` because `c` becomes just another name for the thing you passed in.  The ampersand is just the notation that was chosen by the designer of C++.  Aliasing is quite different from two distinct objects having the same value (that's just called equality).  With aliasing there is only one object!  It just has two names.

Comment: Ok ok I think I'm getting it... So myFunc(int &c) is the same mem addy as my  *a.    Also myFunc(&myNum) with void myFunc(int *c) Is the same as myFunc(myNum) with void myFunc(int &c) ?

Comment: The following two cases are the same: `int x; void f(int& c) {c=1;} f(x);` and `int x; void f(int* c) {*c=1;} f(&x);`.  Both set argument `x` to 1.  How the C++ compiler implements this doesn't matter too much as long as the end effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here.

1. your second line of code `int a = &myNum;   // a equals the address where myNum is storing 30` is wrong;
   you can combine it with line 3 like so:
   `int *a = &myNum; // a equals the address where myNum is stored;
   *a == myNum`.
2. The type `int &` is read as "reference-to-int".  Perhaps the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29#Syntax_and_terminology) can help you understand what this means.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I apologize I can't test because I'm on my iPhone. So about your point #1.... if I cout<< *a I will get the address of myNum and not the value?

Comment: No.  `a` will be the address of `myNum`. The expression `*a` means "dereference `a`", so `cout<<*a` will print the value at the address, i.e. `myNum`.

Answer (score 1):

Both pieces of code are valid and your understanding of pointers in the first piece of code is correct. However, the ampersand (&) in the two pieces of code are actually different things. (Like how * is both the dereference and multiplication operator)

The second piece of code shows how the & can be used to pass variables to a function by reference. Normally if you had code like this:

```
int a;

void foo(int bar) {
    bar = 3;
}

int main() {
    a = 5;
    foo(a);
    // a still equals 5
}
```

The call to 'foo()' does not affect the variable you passed to it (`bar` or in this case, `a`). However if you changed this line:

```
void foo(int bar) {
```

to

```
void foo(int &bar) {
```

then it would affect the variable and at the end of the program above, the value of `a` would be 3.

Comment: Ok I am understanding... So is void foo(int &bar) the same as void foo(int *bar) ? Do I get bar = 3 with *bar?  I apologize I'm on my phone so I am not able to test. :)

Comment: It's similar. `void foo(int &bar) { bar = 3; }` does the same thing as `void foo(int *bar) { *bar = 3; }` Basically, with &bar, you don't have to bother dereferencing it.

Comment: Brilliant !!!! Thankyou very much sir...you just made yourself a new friend! :) you explained it 100 times more clearer than my intro to C++ teacher.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ when you pass things by reference using `int &c` you don't need to dereference. You only need to dereference pointers. If it was `int *c` then it would be necessary. Just remember in both cases you change the value of what was passed in the original caller so myNum is now 40.

Comment: So what your saying is:  myFunc(&myNum) with void myFunc(int *c). Is the same as myFunc(myNum) with void myFunc(int &c) ?   Thanks for you helping. :)

Comment: The int a = &myNum is wrong, since address sizes are sizeof(unsigned long) or void * type

Comment: Yea it is *a = &myNum that get the address. Sorry :) did you read my second comment? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the assumptions first:

```
int myNum = 30;

// this won't compile. &myNum is the address of an int (an int *), not an int:
int a = &myNum;   

// *a is a pointer to an int. It received the address of myNum (which is &myNum), 
// and not its value
int *a = &myNum;
```

About the code:

```
void myFunc(int &c)   
// c is passed by reference. This is a kind of "hidden pointer" that
// allows using the variable as if it was not a pointer but the pointed variable. 
// But as this reference and the variable that was passed by the caller (myNum 
// in your example) share the same address (this is the property of a reference), 
// any modification of the value of c inside myFunc modifies it in the 
// caller's scope too (so here, it modifies myNum). 
{
  c += 10;
  cout<< c;
}

int main()
{
  int myNum = 30;
  myFunc(myNum);  // displays 40

  // What follows displays 40 as well, due to the fact 
  // c was passed by reference to myFunc that added 10 to it       
  cout<< myNum ;  
}
```

> So when I do c+=10 it's going to add 10 to the memory address and not
>   the value 30. Is that correct?

No, 10 was added to the value of `c` by `myFunc`.
As `c` is a reference (a "hidden pointer to") that received `myNum`, `myNum` was modified as well.